# Tool for monitoring kernel driver messages? What are the options?

Tags: drivers, logs, devices, monitoring

I'm working on a kernel-level device driver that sends requests to an underlying piece of hardware. Those requests have a fixed length and a given layout (including multiple fields with encoded values, etc. -- typical stuff).

This piece of hardware is not USB, so a USB sniffer won't do.

I would like to see the flow of such requests, in order, through some UI similar to WireShark, where I can click on a given request and have it decoded for me.

Do such monitoring tools exist in this landscape?

Comment: A microkernel might have a uniform messaging infrastructure that's used for basically "everything", but Linux is not a microkernel. So the available message monitoring depends entirely on what kind of hardware the driver uses and how it does its messaging. Does it use *any* known infrastructure: i2c? Bluetooth? PCI? GPIO? Pin control? If the driver operates directly on the hardware, then any monitoring facilities would have to be in the driver itself, and presumably you would already know about them. Please describe the driver in terms of what it *is*, rather than only what it *is not*.

Comment: The driver communicates with a PCIe device via memory-mapped I/O addresses. It places those [128-byte] requests in the mapped address space, and some internal processes which I ignore ensure the requests land where they need to land.

I am assuming that any existing solutions would require calling a library in order to log these requests.

Are there ready-made, even commercial, solutions for this use-case?

Comment: Accessing memory-mapped I/O is essentially the same as accessing regular RAM, as far as program code is concerned. Unless the driver has some debugging feature to send copies of the requests to some other place (like a virtual file in debugfs, which would give you copies of any requests submitted when the file is opened by a suitable utility that handles the presentation), the only way to monitor MMIO I know would be to connect a logic analyzer to the bus and program it to capture the requests. Adding debugging features to the driver would probably be easier, if you have the source code.

Comment: Ethernet and USB traffic have sniffers because there is an underlying software abstraction to which the sniffer can plug into: no matter what network protocol or USB device we're talking about, it's still using the same low-level software functions that can be intercepted. But for MMIO, the only available abstraction is *memory access* - and the processor already does it in hardware. You might be able to add kernel tracepoints to the driver and use generic kernel debugging tools to catch the MMIO accesses, but for that, you would probably also need the source code of the driver.